# How can I calculate the HSYNC and VSYNC for the RK043FN48H-CT672B from the datasheet?

Tags: lcd, stm32f7

I'm working with STM32F746G Disco Board and wanted to understand how these values are calculated. The HSYNC, VSYNC, HBP, HFP, VBP, VFP values mentioned in data sheet (https://cache.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/RK043FN02H-CT.pdf) and the driver file (rk043fn48h.h) in examples provided by ST are totally different. Could anyone explain about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Application Note of TFT display.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00287603-lcdtft-display-controller-ltdc-on-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Here is link and in PDF there is example of RK043FN48H display.

In default STM32F7-Disco board they have taken,

HSYNC = 40(any number grater than 1)

HBP = 13(grater than 8)

HFP = 32(grater than 2)

VSYNC = 9(any number grater than 1)

VBP = 2(grater than 2)

VHP = 2(grater than 1)